Nuclear war movie ending
I think this scene is from the ending of a movie, but I could be wrong. 
The world (earth I think) is seen from outer space while the camera slowly zooming out. A missile (a nuclear warhead?), only seen as a small white line, is fired away from one country towards another.
When the missile hits its target a single high pitched piano note is played. After the impact another small white line is seem from the targeted country. When it hits another piano note is played.
More and more missiles are fired while the camera zooms out.
Can anyone help me identify where this scene is from?

Slightly similar scene in Terminator 3 which can be seen here, but it's a string section. There's also a scene from Damnation Alley (seen here from 0:40 onwards) where we see Earth after it was ravaged by nuclear war and there's a single high pitched piano note repeated in the background, but we zoom in on it.

That sounds exactly like the ending in the 2012 comedy movie Iron Sky.



